# Salesforce plugin configuration page

Tags: plugins, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Salesforce gurus,

I'm thinking of a Salesforce plugin which requires some configuration performed by admin prior it is added to the page, but I cannot find anywhere how can I make it? I can create components with `Lightning` users will interact with, custom objects with `XML`, controllers with `Apex` and etc - tons of materials here - but how can I create plugin setup page for admin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Um... whatever you want?

If you have "just" a lightning component - you can expose variables with `@api` and then add them to the meta file so they appear as configurable properties when admin drag&drops the component to their pages.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags (old but for me reads better than https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-configuration-tags.html)

If you need more config stored as data - consider custom metadata, custom settings, maybe even a custom object... Think if you'd want this config to be deployable / survive a sandbox refresh or not. For example config like fields, options displayed I'd want to survive so custom metadata. But API connection to third party server I'd probably want to differentiate test vs prod so I would keep it in data (sobject or custom setting) and it could be empty on refresh or you could wipe it with script that runs afte sandbox is copied: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm

If the normal UI for your config is not enough... well, make an admin-only component or Visualforce page where you'd mass insert config etc? Could be a LWC + tab and you'd ship your plugin with 2 permission sets, 1 for admins with the tab visible, apex class added and 1 for regular users without access to the config tool.

If your plugin is a real app (managed package) for appexchange - there's this option: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/92355/799